# Test a single variable multiple times in python in a single statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm learning Python at uni and have been told how logic operators and conditional statements work. My question is: is there any way of condensing code such as this?

```
if (day != "Sunday" and day != "Saturday" and day != "Friday" and day != "Thursday" and day != "Wednesday" and day != "Tuesday" and day != "Monday"):
    print "That is not a day"
    return 0
```

Any advice is appreciated and I understand the above example is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `in` keyword.

```
if day not in ("Sunday", "Saturday", "Friday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday"):
```

Comment: For this particular case we can also do: `import calendar; if day not in calendar.day_name: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Because if day is `"Monday"` then `if` won't be evaluated and it's enough to skip all other conditions in your `if` resulting it not be satisfied. This happens because of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

When you write:

```
if (not a) and (not b)
```

This is the same as ([De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)):

```
if not (a or b)
```

Which is not what you meant.